# How do I import unit test library in kotlin interactive?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, kotlin

How do I run kotlin interactive prompt `kotlinc` and be able to import the junit library ? Now when I do it I get an `unresolved reference` error:

```
>>> import org.junit.Test
error: unresolved reference: junit
import org.junit.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use external libraries, you must tell Kotlin where to find them. Hava a look at `kotlinc -help`

At first, you must download the junit library (e.g. from http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar).

Next, point to that library in your compile command with:

```
kotlinc -classpath junit-4.12.jar YourClass.kt
```

---

There are of course situations where using the plain `kotlinc` command is used by hand. I can't think of one, but there are some for sure. I strongly suggest you, to have a look into build tools, like Gradle or Maven. They will make your life easier. For example, https://github.com/guenhter/kotlin-unit-testing.git is a gradle repo using Kotlin and Junit.